# How to create a playable rectangle in SpriteKit on iPhone X

Tags: swift, iphone, sprite-kit

I'm a newbie in Swift and SpriteKit. I'm trying to develop a simple 2D game for iPhone X, so I want to draw a playable area where I can put game's sprites. The problem is that when I draw the rectangle it fits the screen width, but not the screen height.

The GameScene size is 2048x1536, with anchor point in (0.5, 0.5).
The default screen orientation is landscape.

This is what I did at the moment:

GameViewController.swift

```swift
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
}
```

GameScene.swift

```swift
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let rectangle = SKShapeNode(rect: self.frame)
        rectangle.strokeColor = .green
        rectangle.lineWidth = 20
        rectangle.zPosition = 1
        addChild(rectangle)

    }
}
```

When I run this code, the rectangle green borders fit the width of the screen (in landscape), so I can see them, but the top and bottom borders are off-screen.

My purpose is to have a playable rect as high as the phone screen, and his width should be screen width - left safe area insets (to exclude the notch from the playable area).

Thank you.

Comment: try 'scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill'

Comment: Hi @TonyMkenu, I tried but it looks like the scene and his content are "zoomed in".

Comment: Because resize fill resizes to @1x. (You really should be developing in points not pixels).  Iphone x in points is 812x375

Comment: You need to understand aspect ratio......  your rectangle  is 4:3 iphone x is 39:18.  When conforming to landscape, you get  156:117 vs 156:72. You have an extra 45 lines of scene that needs to go somewhere.  If your target device is IPhone X, then make your scene conform to it.